# React App: How to display data from API using fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to display school data from an external API using React. I'm just trying to display a school name to start. The school name appears in the console, but it doesn't show up in the browser. The API call is correct, as it works in Postman. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schoolName: '',
      // schoolData: {}
    }
  }

  fetchSchool(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const apiKey = 'XdOHSc8fKhMKidPu2HWqCZmMy9OxtCJamGC580Bi';
    const fields = `_fields=school.name,2015.aid.median_debt.completers.overall,2015.cost.tuition.in_state&school.name=${this.state.schoolName}`;
    const requestUrl = `https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?&api_key=${apiKey}&${fields}`;

    const school = fetch(requestUrl).then((res) => res.json()).then((data) => console.log(data.results[0]['school.name']));

    this.setState({
      schoolName: school
      // schoolData: school
    })
    console.log(this.state.schoolName);
  }

  setSchool(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      schoolName: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    // const schoolname = this.state.schoolName[0];
    // const {schooName} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form action="/school" method="GET" id="myform">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" id="enter_text" onChange={this.setSchool.bind(this)} />
            <button onClick={this.fetchSchool.bind(this)} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id="text-enter-button button submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div>
        <p>School: {this.state.school} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I recommend to remove the value for apiKey if it is sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is asynchronous. Therefore, `setState` is being called before the data has been fetched.

To fix this, call `this.setState` from inside of your `then` function

```
const school = fetch(requestUrl)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.results[0]['school.name'])
    this.setState({
      schoolName: data.results[0]['school.name'],
      schoolData: data.results
    })
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked...almost. The school name displays in the browser, but it displays as I type it, instead of after I click 'submit'.

Comment: remove `onChange={this.setSchool.bind(this)}` from your `input` element

Comment: This gave me a new error: cannot read property of 'school.name' of undefined(in the fetch request)

Comment: Okay add the code back to the `input` element.  Right now, it looks like you are printing `this.state.schoolName`. What do you want to print to the page?

Comment: I want to print the name of the school that the user searches for. My next step is to print specific data from the school (defined in 'fields').

Comment: Did you even write this code? Because it seems like you have no idea what this code is supposed to do

Comment: JosanIracheta, you are right. The solution you posted should work. @user8767190 upvote this answer if it resolved your query, this specific query. If you have other questions post a new question with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

In your render method change this line because `schoolName` is your state variable and not `school`.

```
<p>School: {this.state.school} </p>
```

to

```
<p>School: {this.state.schoolName} </p>
```